# Login with RSA key in phpseclib fails (times out)

Tags: php, ssh, rsa, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib and I am trying to login using an RSA key:

```
$ssh = new SSH2('<server_domain_name>');
$key = new RSA();
$key->load(file_get_contents('<private_key_path>'));
if($ssh->login('root',$key)){
    echo "Logged In!!!";
} else {
    echo "Login failed!";
}
```

but login fails! Looking inside the SSH2 class I can see that logging in with RSA key takes place in the _login_helper() function (correct if I am wrong) which is called by the _login() function which is called by the login() function (under circumstances).

login() -> _login() -> _login_helper()

But this piece of code:

```
if (!($this->bitmap & self::MASK_CONSTRUCTOR)) {
    if (!$this->_connect()) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in the _login() function always returns false and by so the execution never reaches the _login_helper() function. The reason for the above part of code returning false is the default values of these variables/constants:

```
var $bitmap = 0;
const MASK_CONNECTED     = 0x00000002;
```

I am little bit frustrated. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that login returns/fails after a few seconds. Adding a few ECHOs in the _connect() method I can see that the method times out while waiting for server data. During the execution of this loop:

```
while (!feof($this->fsock) && !preg_match('#(.*)^(SSH-(\d\.\d+).*)#ms', $data, $matches))
```

the server outputs just one line saying "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3" and then (the second time the loop executes) it times out here:

```
if (!@stream_select($read, $write, $except, $sec, $usec) && !count($read)) {
```

**EDIT 2:** The SSH logs of the side that I am trying to connect to say:

Connection closed by THE_SSH_SERVER_IP
Nov  4 23:09:58 web1 sshd[10316]: Did not receive identification string fromTHE_ WEB_SERVER_IP

Comment: What'd be more helpful are the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and then `echo $ssh->getLog()` after the login fails. In lieu of that...  who knows. Maybe PHP isn't able to read your private key due to permissions. Maybe your private key doesn't correspond to the public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for the user you're trying to login as.

Comment: getLog() returns an empty string. The key is readable by file_get_contents and I can use it successfully through a console. In fact, if I use the ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() with that key, it works great. If the function that makes the RSA authentication is indeed the _privatekey_login(), then the values of $bitmask and MASK_CONNECTED never let the code get at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpseclib reads the servers server identification string before it sends it's own. This is what PuTTY does. As evidence of this here is a sample log file from PuTTY when I tried to connect to localhost:4022:

```
Event Log: Writing new session log (SSH packets mode) to file: putty.log
Event Log: Looking up host "127.0.0.1"
Event Log: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 4022
Event Log: Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu1
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
```

Here are what the SSH specs say:

```
   When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
   identification string.  This identification string MUST be

      SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2

Note that it does not say that one side has to send before the other side. Both sides should have the content available for retrieval immediately. If your SSH server is only going to conditionally make the content available for retrieval after the client has sent it's identification string then your SSH server is buggy. Let me know what server you're using an I'll open up a bug report on it.

In the mean time here's a modified version of phpseclib that sends the identification string first instead of reading it first:

https://github.com/terrafrost/phpseclib/tree/send-identifier-first

Let me know if that works for you. And let me know what you're using as your server.

Comment: As I have posted above, the SSH server is "OpenSSH_4.3". The O.S is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! 
Hmm! Is that a bug of the OpenSSH server?

Comment: As far as I remember, this was a default SSH Server installation that I chose during ubuntu installation.

Comment: Could be some quirk with how the network is setup too idk. Like why do some SSH servers have really small window sizes and others have really large ones? I don't think that's a setting in the conf file. Maybe it changes from version to version but my money is on it being auto-determined by network settings idk lol. Anyway glad to hear that it works!